# Keras ImageDataGenerator() expect 3D data and 4-rank tensor at once?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've been trying to use `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()` on the MNIST for extra examples.

I'm using a fully-connected network in Keras on top of Keras. I begin by reshaping the 3D MNIST into 4D tensors before building and compiling a model, then I use data augmentation to help fit the model.

```python
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)


model = Sequential(name="mlp")

model.add(ll.InputLayer([28, 28]))
model.add(ll.Flatten())

model.add(ll.Dense(512, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.04)))
model.add(ll.Activation('relu'))

model.add(ll.Dense(512, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.04)))
model.add(ll.Activation('relu'))


model.add(ll.Dense(256, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.04)))
model.add(ll.Activation('relu'))

model.add(ll.Dense(128, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.04)))
model.add(ll.Activation('relu'))

model.add(ll.Dense(32, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.04)))
model.add(ll.Activation('relu'))

model.add(ll.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile("adam", "categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])


gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=8, width_shift_range=0.08, shear_range=0.3,
                         height_shift_range=0.08, zoom_range=0.08)

test_gen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = gen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64)
test_generator = test_gen.flow(X_test, y_test, batch_size=64)

...
model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=60000//64, epochs=5, 
                    validation_data=test_generator, validation_steps=10000//64)
```

I get this error:

```python
  5 model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=60000//64, epochs=5, 
    ----> 6                     validation_data=test_generator, validation_steps=10000//64)

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_6 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (256, 28, 28, 1)
```

But then when I omit it converting to a 4d tensor, this happens:

```python
     52 test_gen = ImageDataGenerator()
    ---> 53 train_generator = gen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64)
         54 test_generator = test_gen.flow(X_test, y_test, batch_size=64)

ValueError: ('Input data in `NumpyArrayIterator` should have rank 4. You passed an array with shape', (50000, 28, 28))
```

It seems that the train and test generator objects generate 4D tensors, but the model, itself, wants 3D tensors.

Comment: please write model code

Comment: Your first error indicates your model is the issue, not the ImageDataGenerator. More details would help answer your question. One more small thing to rule out: if you specify `batch_size=64` in the generator, put the same in the `model.fit_generator` call. Otherwise the default is `32`. This caused a problem for me in the past.

Comment: Thanks, @DexterMorgan. I've updated the post. I tried using `batch_size=64` in the `fit_generator` method, but I'm getting an unexpected keyword argument error. Regardless, I changed the sizes to all reflect a batch of 32, to be safe. This doesn't change the Error.  EDIT: I should also add that the model works fine without data augmentation by using the `.fit` method, so the issue is likely the model's compatibility with ImageDataGenerator, not the model, itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your data is `(batch, 28, 28, 1)` while your model (the input layer) is expecting `(batch, 28, 28)`.

Solving this is as simple as changing the input shape of the model:

```
#you don't need to add an input layer, actually, just pass the shape to the first layer:

 model = Sequential(name="mlp")
 model.add(ll.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28,1)))
```